# vim editor on Linux: How to reduce numbering indentation

Tags: vim

I am working on RHEL 6.6. When i open vim editor and set numbers, the line numbers appear but there is a very big indentation from the left side of the screen. is there a way to reduce that gap: Here is a sample:

```
  1 #!/bin/sh
  2
  3 echo "Hello World"
  4
  5 echo "bye"
```

Its almost 6 spaces empty to the left of numbers 1, 2, 3 ...

I tried googling but could not find an answer to this problem (though found some other useful commands around vim)

[image]

Here is the image for set numberwidth:
[image]

Here is the image for vim version:
[image]

Comment: I really don't think you tried googling hard enough. `:h 'numberwidth'`

Comment: nanny - ":h numberwith" did not work, i get the following error: E435: Couldn't find tag, just guessing!

Comment: You must have typed it in wrong. You need to set `numberwidth` in the same way that you turned on numbers in the first place.

Comment: I think you're not using full Vim, but vim-tiny, or vi. [edit] your question to incllude the output of `vim --version`.

Comment: Hello muru - here is my vim version: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Feb 17 2012 10:23:31) Included patches: 1-411. Please let me know if this suffices or i should get the entire output uploaded (and sorry for the late reply guys, i had to run multiple offices to get my DL re-instated)

Comment: Hello nanny, i typed when vim was open, the following ":set numberwidth=2" and hit enter, cursor just moved to first line. Added the snapshot in the original question

Comment: @JavaTec I would like to see the entire output. Can you check if you have `vim-enhanced` or `vim-minimal` installed (`yum list installed vim-enhanced`, perhaps).

Comment: Hello muru, it seems like vim-enhanced. PFA the screenshot in original question

Answer (score 3):

Just adapt it with the width you want (the `4` there is the number of characters you want the number to have).

```
echo "set numberwidth=4" >> ~/.vimrc
```

Note that you must have the `+linebreak` compile option on in order for this to work. To check if you have this flag type `:echo has('linebreak')` in your `vim` (`0` means you don't have it).

Comment: hi Kira - this did not change the width/margin either. i did not get any error but no change in the margin either

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: Hi Kira unfortunately, this one also not working. Here's what i did: opened vim     typed:echo has('linebreak'), no error but no change/response either.

Comment: Man... you've typed `enter` after that... Right? Also, note that the output of that command will show up right in the botton of the screen, where you have just typed.

Comment: yes Kira, i did hit enter after that command (and sorry for the late reply, i had to run multiple offices to get my DL re-instated)