# How to reduce numbering indent in vi in 19.10?

Tags: terminal, vim, vi, window

Upgraded to 19.10 and my terminal window without numbers is ok

[image]

but with numbers (:set nu)

[image]

it now has a large annoying indent!

I tried the solution at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252200/10043 but it did not help or change the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As i was posting the problem, I found the solution...

I didn't have vim, I just had vi !

so:

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

fixed that and now the indent has gone away!

Comment: That cannot be right.  Ubuntu does not have a `vi` package, and `vi` could not have produced the screenshot because it does not do colour.

Comment: @JdeBP Ubuntu has a `vim.tiny` though and I find it plausible that it would be missing `+linebreak` which is required for `'numberwidth'` to work. But I definitely agree that this answer is really unsatisfactory.

Comment: It's hard to misread having vim.tiny, which is VIM, as "I didn't have vim", though.

Comment: The command "vim" did NOT work.  The command "vi" did.  That's why I had to install "vim"

Comment: My experience in 2020 is the facts here.  The other comments seem based on opinions of previous incidents.  I am just reporting what I experienced, "believe it or not".

Comment: I also experienced this problem on two separate machines doing fresh 19.10 installs.